# How to find,where a .h file is referenced in project, which is listed in External dependencise folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, external-dependencies

I have a xyz.h file displayed in my "External Dependencies" folder, I want to find where it is refrenced in my project. How can I find it.!? I want to remove that dependency.
How to find- where a .h file is referenced in my project, which is listed in External dependencise folder.
Simple search of that 'xyz.h' throught out the solution doesnt get any search result. So it is not directly referenced. Now how can I find - from where it is being referenced. I have VS 2010 with me.

Comment: Is this for a new project? What dependency exactly is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply remove/rename the header file and try to compile. The error messages will tell you where dependencies to xyz.h are.

Comment: Only if you are lucky. It may be that it will not come for your project mate due to different level of self-containment for the libraries used around, etc. I think the user should be more specific.